# Error INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK - Cordova/Ionic

Tags: android, xml, cordova, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to target a different API LEVEL from the one set. I've already tried to change:

- config.xml
- AndroidManifest.xml (both android and CordovaLib folders)
- project.properties (both android and CordovaLib folders)
- build.gradle -> android folder

I've used the commands:

- `ionic platform add android`
- `ionic platform rm android`
- `ionic platform add android@4.0.1`
- `ionic platform add android@4`
- `ionic platform add android@3`
- and `cordova` variations

Nothing worked.

Because im using *Crosswalk* *plugin* the minSdkVersion needs to bem at least 16 and Cordova's 4.

The changes I've done:

**app/config.xml**

```
<platform name="android">
 <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
 <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19"/>
  . . .
</platform>
```

**../platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
```

**../platforms/android/CordovaLib/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
```

**../platforms/android/projects.properties and ../platforms/android/CordovaLib/projects.properties**

```
target=android-21 #to target-19 
apk-configurations=
renderscript.opt.level=O0
android.library=true
```

*Although it says that the file is overwritten, it does not happen, because while **build**, I was watching if asked to reload at gedit.*

If anything is missing, please let me know ! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using **Cordova** version 8.0.0. Go to **build.gradle** and change `defaultMinSdkVersion` to 16. See below

```
project.ext {
    defaultBuildToolsVersion="25.0.2" //String
    defaultMinSdkVersion=16 //Change here - Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 4.1.2
    defaultTargetSdkVersion=22 //Integer
    defaultCompileSdkVersion=26 //Integerdefault
}
```